# how to fix select primeng?

Tags: html, angular, primeng

I have a problem in select search.
I can't search!

[image]

My code:

```
  <select2 [data]="listuser" width="88%" style="font-size: 15px"
                         (valueChanged)="changeUser($event)"  [value]="obj.id_cible"></select2>
```

Comment: It seems the `data` or `value` is null which is causing an issue.

Comment: @ApoorvaChikara I removed the value still have the same error